# PRIMENG: How to pass row index into onRowSelect event?

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using onRowSelect on my datatable, but want to pass the row index into the function.  I know you can pass row index using templates for p-column, but i want the event to fired onRowSelect and not on column click.  Is index included somewhere on $event ?

Comment: did you resolved this problem ?

Comment: @Chandru no have not found a solution to using onRowSelect.  But i made a work around and created a template for each column, setting width and height to 100% and passing row index through each column.  This way it is pretty much the same as using onRowSelect, just not a pretty solution

Answer (score 1):

row index is not included as part of the event data.  On the `onRowSelect` callback, you could simply perform an `indexOf(data)` on the array you are using to populate your datatable.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response.  I considered using this method, but having index would be better incase there are duplicate rows in the data.

Comment: oddly enough, the function knows the index, but doesn't include it in the event at all.  You could always modify the function to include the index in the event

Answer (score 1):

With PrimeNG, they have the option to add a `[pSelectableRowIndex]` property. To do this, on your template body, add `let-rowIndex="rowIndex"` (you can name this how you prefer such as `let-ri`.

Now on your `<tr>`, add `[pSelectableRowIndex]="rowIndex"`. The index will now be included in the $event on selection.

Example:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
  <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData" [pSelectableRowIndex]="rowIndex">
    <td>{{rowData['val']}}</td>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
```